Text inside a Textarea component is getting masked even after adding `data-clarity-unmask="true"` attribute - MS Clarity
I have a textarea input element. The text inside that is getting masked in the recordings.
As mentioned in the Docs/FAQs, I have added the data-clarity-unmask="true" attribute to the element. The masked mode is also set to "Relaxed" from the Clarity Settings. However, the data inside is still getting masked in the recordings.
